# Необходимо ли обучать модель NARX (Nonlinear autoregressive exogenous model) перед использование?

Tags: математика, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, neuralbase

В данный момент занимаюсь написанием работы связанной с прогнозированием данных для получения лучших характеристик предиктора. Система должна быть легкой. Пал взгляд на сеть типа NARX. Но есть загвоздка, не могу понять, сеть обучается каждый раз, когда на нее поступают новые данные, как происходит на обычном линейном адаптивном предсказателе (ALP), либо сеть уже перед применением должна быть обучена и веса ее не меняются, хотя везде в литературе представляют ее как систему похожую на обычный ALP.
Если ситуация как во втором варианте, то к примеру система может измениться и смысла в предсказателе уже не будет.
Например на странице https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ug/design-time-series-narx-feedback-neural-networks.html посвященной моделированию временных рядов с применением NARX говорится, что нужно выбрать данные для обучения. Так вот, хотелось бы узнать, сеть предобучается или она находится "пустая" и после того как пошли отсчеты сигнала, сеть начинает подстраиваться под функцию то есть обучаться в реальном времени.

---

Заранее большое спасибо за ответы!!!!